# Give examples of subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $BA(x_0)$ is a single point and $BA(x_0)$ contains at least two points.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, approximation

In $(\mathbb{R}^3, \|\cdot\|_1)$ consider the vector $x_0=(1,1,1)$. For any subspace $A\subset \mathbb R^3$ denote $$BA(x_0)=\{y^*\in A:\|y^*-x_0\|\leq\|y-x_0\|,\forall y\in A\}.$$
Give examples of non-trivial subspaces $A \subset\mathbb{R}^3$ such that:

a) $BA(x_0)$ is a singleton;

b) $BA(x_0)$ contains at least two points.

I'm thinking a line could work for $BA(x_0)$ being unique. For the other one I can only think of trivial subspaces. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: This question seems to be pretty interesting, but I couldn't fully understand it, so here it follows some questions about it:

1) What is the role of the subspace in the definition of $BA(x_0)$?

2) How could it happen of $BA(x_0)$ being a single point and, at the same time, contain at least two points?

Maybe there are some typos.

Comment: @AndréPorto thanks for the observations! I don't know if now it's more understandable.

Comment: The definition of $BA(x_0)$ is still unclear. I made an edit which is still under approval by the trusted community members, that may be a good one. Please let me know if it's alright now.

Comment: Thanks!!  $BA(x_0)$ is the best approximant to $x_0$

Comment: Which subspaces have you already tried?
Have you tried to solve a similar problem in $2$ dimensions already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line should work in both cases.

1. If $A$ is the $z$-axis, that is, $A=\{(0,0,a): a\in\mathbb R\}$ then $BA(x_0)=\{(0,0,1)\}$, for
   $$
   \|(1,1,1)-(0,0,a)\|_1= 2+|1-a| \geq 2 = \|(1,1,1)-(0,0,1)\|_1,
   $$
   and whenever $a\neq 1$,
   $$
   \|(1,1,1)-(0,0,a)\|_1= 1+1+|1-a| > 2.
   $$
2. If $A$ is the line where $y=-x$ and $z=1$, that is, $A=\{(a,-a,1): a\in\mathbb R\}$. Notice that, for any $a\in\mathbb R$,
   $$
   \|(1,1,1)-(a,-a,1)\|_1 = |1-a| + |1+a|.
   $$
   If $|a|\leq 1$, then $1-a, 1+a\geq0$, and
   $$
   \|(1,1,1)-(a,-a,1)\|_1 = 1-a + 1+a=2.
   $$
   If $a>1$, then $1-a<0$ and $1+a>0$, so
   $$
   \|(1,1,1)-(a,-a,1)\|_1 = a-1 + 1+a = 2a > 2.
   $$
   If $a<-1$, then $1-a>0$ and $1+a<0$, so
   $$
   \|(1,1,1)-(a,-a,1)\|_1 = 1-a - 1-a = -2a > 2.
   $$
   So we conclude that $BA(x_0)$ is the line segment $\{(a,-a,1): a\in[-1,1]\}$.